# When exacty is the object initialized?

Tags: java, object, initialization, instance

I want to ask you when is the exact moment when an object is initialized

For example I have this simple Java code:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setName("John");
      student.setId(123);
   }
}
```

So when exactly is the student object initialized? Is it initialized when `new Student()` is executed? Or when `Student student = new Student()` is executed? Or after setters are executed? Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by *initialize*. As for `Student student = new Student();`, the operator precedence will mandate that the constructor be called before the assignment is processed.

Comment: The student is initialized when new Student() is executed. Just calling Student student only declares the variable but does not initialize it. Calling Student student = new Student() declares and initializes in same line

Answer (score 3):

It's initialized when new + constructor is called.

As states [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

> Each of these statements has three parts (discussed in detail below):
>
> **Declaration**: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that
>     associate a variable name with an object type.
>
> **Instantiation**: The
>       new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
>
> **Initialization**: The new operator is followed by a call to a
>       constructor, which initializes the new object.

Comment: Specifically, the instantiation part is `new Student()`, initialization invokes the `Student()` constructor, declaration is the realization that `student` is a `Student` as specified in `Student student`, and assignment occurs when the `Student` instantiated by `new Student()` is associated with the `Student` declared by `Student student`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it initialized when `new Student()` is executed?

Yes. When the resulting object is returned, it has been initialized (by the constructor code).

> Or after setters are executed?

The fields of the object are initialized by the time the constructor returns. They may be set to `null` or `""` or `0` or similar, but they're initialized with *some* value.

If it's not valid for a `Student` object to have `null` or whatever for those fields, then the constructor should accept the values for them as parameters, or the class should expose a builder-style interface for building an instance, so that by the time you have a `Student` instance, you know the fields are filled in with meaningful values. Whether that's necessary is domain-specific.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your constructor class. Probably line three, but if your mutator methods create new objects then line 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

It get initialized when **new Student()** is executed.

- **new Student()** - this calls the constructor of the Student Class.

After that, the resulting object is assigned to the '**student**' variable where the data type is **Student**.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever '**new**' keyword is invoked, the object is instantiated and the constructor is called resulting in object initialization.

First of all, see the difference between a setter and constructor and their pros and cons.

**Constructor:**

1) A constructor is called when an object is created.

2) They are only called once per object.

3) You may use the constructor to set values at the point of instantiation.

4) It does not allow any return type.

5) A constructor is invoked implicitly.

**Setter:**

1) A setter is called to change the value of the object after it was initialized.

2) A setter can be called any number of times.

3) You may use the setter to set values after the point of instantiation.

4) It allows return type.

5) A setter is invoked explicitly.

**Conclusion:**

1) Object is initialized when new Student() is executed

2) Use constructor if you think initialization is mandatory and you have the required values before you can use the object.

3) Use the setter method when the initialization of the variable is non-mandatory and you don't have the values at the time of object initialization.

4) Generally, we should avoid setter as it somehow violates the principle of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Student student = new Student();

When you call new and then the constructor you are creating an object of the same type of your constructor class, the object that is receiving the new + constructor must be the same type.

Another example:

Object that must be the same as your class + name of the object signal = then new plus constructor;

`Example exaple = new Example();`

Answer (score -1):

When you call

```
Student student = new Student();
```

you are creating an object in memory. Once created, you can use the object's methods, like getters and setters.